# Around usage results

Tags: core-language, error-propagation, around

Why is

```
Around[10, 1]^2
```

100. +- 20

and

```
Around[10, 1] Around[10, 1]
```

giving 100 +- 14 ?

Just curious I would suspect them to be the same but I'm not an expert on this for sure.

Comment: If the intent for `Around` in *Mathematica* is for propagating errors, then this is almost certainly a bug. Interestingly enough, I think the second one is correct, whereas the first is not.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's a subtlety here.

When operating together multiple `Around`s, the two uncertainties will be considered separate and independent (in the statistical sense).  Thus the result will be different from squaring a single one.

Consider

```
N@StandardDeviation@
  TransformedDistribution[
    x y, 
   {x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[10, 1], 
    y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[10, 1]}]

(* 14.1774 *)
```

versus

```
N@StandardDeviation@TransformedDistribution[x^2, {x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[10, 1]}]

(* 20.0499 *)
```

The same can also be observed with addition:

```
Around[10, 1] + Around[10, 1]
(* Around[20., 1.4142135623730951`] *)

2 Around[10, 1]
(* Around[20., 2.] *)
```

---

To specify that all occurrences of an `Around` expression are the same, use [`AroundReplace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AroundReplace.html).

For example, compare

```
x^2 + x /. x -> Around[1, .1]
(* Around[2., 0.223606797749979] *)
```

with

```
AroundReplace[x^2 + x, x -> Around[1, .1]]
(* Around[2., 0.30000000000000004`] *)
```

Comment: Also, `AroundReplace[
 x1 x2, {{x1, x2} -> VectorAround[{10., 10.}, {{1., 1.}, 1.}]}]` vs `AroundReplace[
 x1 x2, {{x1, x2} -> VectorAround[{10., 10.}, {{1., 1.}, 0.}]}]`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks a beautiful demonstration of VectorAround.

Comment: @Searke Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

How Around works should be explained by an example.

For an el. Double cable of length l, conductor distance a and conductor radius r, the following values were measured. We are looking for the absolute uncertainty of the mean value of the inductance L:
[image]

```
mittlereMessunsicherheit[f_, vars_List, dvars_List] := Sqrt@Inner[Times, Grad[f, vars]^2, dvars^2]

params = {
   l -> Quantity[2, "km"], dl -> Quantity[10, "m"],
   r -> Quantity[2, "cm"], dr -> Quantity[50, "\[Mu]m"],
   a -> Quantity[0.3, "m"], da -> Quantity[3, "mm"],
   \[Mu]0 -> UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "MagneticConstant"]]
   };
vars = {l, r, a};
dvars = {dl, dr, da};
L = \[Mu]0/\[Pi] l (Log[(a - r)/r] + 1/4);

dL = mittlereMessunsicherheit[L, vars, dvars]
```

[image]

```
UnitConvert[L /. params, "mH"] \[PlusMinus] UnitConvert[dL /. params, "mH"] // EngineeringForm
```

[image]

Same calculation now with `Around`:

```
params2 = {
   l -> Around[Quantity[2, "km"], Quantity[10, "m"]],
   r -> Around[Quantity[2, "cm"], Quantity[50, "\[Mu]m"]],
   a -> Around[Quantity[0.3, "m"], Quantity[3, "mm"]],
   \[Mu]0 -> UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "MagneticConstant"]]
   };
L = UnitConvert[L /. params2, "mH"]
```

[image]

Let us turn to OP's questions.

1.)

```
Around[10, 1]*Around[10, 1]
```

[image]

We have

```
M = x*y;
dM = mittlereMessunsicherheit[M, {x, y}, {dx, dy}]
```

[image]

```
params = {x -> 10, dx -> 1, y -> 10, dy -> 1};
```

and we obtain

```
M \[PlusMinus] dM /. params // N
```

[image]

2.)

```
Around[10, 1]^2
```

[image]

```
M = x^2;
dM = mittlereMessunsicherheit[M, {x}, {dx}]
```

[image]

```
M \[PlusMinus] dM /. {x -> 10, dx -> 1}
```

[image]

I explained `Around` in a different way, as Szabolcs formulated it in his answer. The error calculation is well known to us, but that `Around` performs the same calculation has not been known.